# Accessing a possibly dead disk

Tags: linux, data-recovery

I am trying to access data from an older hard-disk of mine.The disk in question, is an old 500Gb sata drive that was used with a windows machine. Currently, I am trying to access the drive on Linux.

When connected, it shows up as an uninitialized drive on Linux. With `fdisk` I get an IO error.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you can see it in Linux, the disk isn't "dead". You could start by using TestDisk (http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) to see if you are able to find the old filesystem partitions and navigate around the drive. If the disk has physical problems (bad or unrecoverable sectors) you might need to use a tool like SpinRite (https://www.grc.com/spinrite.htm) on it to attempt to repair it before you can do further work.

Comment: The in-board disk controller is good, the disk might be dead. In my opinion there is a high probability `dd` wont work

Answer (score 0):

IO error tells you you either have a disk problem, or if you are lucky, maybe it has to do with the power take or data cable.

Change the power line and data cable, and try using dd to export it to your hard disk, you may be able to work with the image and extract some or all the info:

```
dd bs=4M if=/dev/whateverdisk of=/home/user/diskimage.img
```

Comment: `dd` is a terrible tool for this. Consider `dd_rescue` instead. (Search here on unix.SE for it.)

Comment: I did try using `dd` to grab the mbr (assuming that its not GPT). But it failed. `parted` just hangs without doing anything. 

I haven't heard of dd_rescue will give that a try tomorrow.